# React Routes are not working properly the URl changes but its rendering the one same page on any link i click ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

whenever i click on any link, it changes the  URL but  its show's me only one page."Job Category"

```
import App from "./App";
import User from "./components/UserManagment/Users";
import Agents from "./components/UserManagment/Agents";
import Usertable from "./components/Usertable";
import Usertopbar from "./components/Usertopbar";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import UserRole from "./components/UserManagment/UserRole";
import Suppliers from "./components/Contact/Suppliers";
import Group from "./components/Contact/Group";
import Mod from "./components/Model";
import Custom from "./components/Contact/Custom";
import Contactmodel from "./components/Contact/Contactmodel";
import Login from "./components/Rm.live/Login";
import Signup from "./components/Rm.live/Signup";
import Rmtable from "./components/Rm.live/rm/Rmtable";
import Blogin from "./components/Bootstrap/Login";
import RmSkills from "./components/Rm.live/rm/RmSkills";
export const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} exact />
        <Route path="/agents" component={Agents} exact />

        <Route patch="/rmskills" component={RmSkills} exact />
        <Route patch="/rmtable" component={Rmtable} exact />
        <Route path="/Blogin" component={Blogin} exact />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/user" component={User} exact />

        <Route path="/userrole" component={UserRole} exact />
        <Route path="/usertable" component={Usertable} exact />
        <Route path="/usertopbar" component={Usertopbar} exact />
        <Route path="/mod" component={Mod} exact />
        <Route Path="/custom" component={Custom} />

        <Route path="/group" component={Group} exact />
        <Route Path="/contactmodel" component={Contactmodel} />

        <Route path="/suppliers" component={Suppliers} exact />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
export default Routes;
```

[when ever i click on any of the link it show me " Job category " page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2UEq.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QbCP.jpg)

Comment: Where are you rendering your routes? Which route is the "Job category" route? I can't see a component named like that. On an other note you are sometimes writing `Path` and `patch`instead of `path`..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your switch inside the browser router. More over re arrange your routes as react will render the first matching route.

```js
import App from "./App";
import User from "./components/UserManagment/Users";
import Agents from "./components/UserManagment/Agents";
import Usertable from "./components/Usertable";
import Usertopbar from "./components/Usertopbar";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import UserRole from "./components/UserManagment/UserRole";
import Suppliers from "./components/Contact/Suppliers";
import Group from "./components/Contact/Group";
import Mod from "./components/Model";
import Custom from "./components/Contact/Custom";
import Contactmodel from "./components/Contact/Contactmodel";
import Login from "./components/Rm.live/Login";
import Signup from "./components/Rm.live/Signup";
import Rmtable from "./components/Rm.live/rm/Rmtable";
import Blogin from "./components/Bootstrap/Login";
import RmSkills from "./components/Rm.live/rm/RmSkills";
export const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/agents" component={Agents} exact />

        <Route patch="/rmskills" component={RmSkills} exact />
        <Route patch="/rmtable" component={Rmtable} exact />
        <Route path="/Blogin" component={Blogin} exact />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/user" component={User} exact />

        <Route path="/userrole" component={UserRole} exact />
        <Route path="/usertable" component={Usertable} exact />
        <Route path="/usertopbar" component={Usertopbar} exact />
        <Route path="/mod" component={Mod} exact />
        <Route Path="/custom" component={Custom} />

        <Route path="/group" component={Group} exact />
        <Route Path="/contactmodel" component={Contactmodel} />

        <Route path="/suppliers" component={Suppliers} exact />

        <Route path="/" component={App} exact />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};
export default Routes;
```